# What is the proper way to handle multiple threads functions using PyGTK in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, pygtk, python-multithreading

When a function takes several seconds to do its job, you need to use threads in order that the application, created using PyGTK, do not freeze.

However, I do not know what is the best way to write code when many functions should use threads.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615124/simple-pygtk-and-threads-example-please/2615243#2615243) which shows how to proceed.

Assuming I have 3 different functions, that means I have to do this:

```
class ThreadFunction1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
       # do something1

class ThreadFunction2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
       # do something2

class ThreadFunction3(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
       # do something3
```

And then I could call separately `ThreadFunction1()`, `ThreadFunction2()` or `ThreadFunction3()`.

I do not think this is the most elegant way to do, that makes a lot of repetitions. How should I do please?